# Search Menu not showing in Fragment

Tags: android, filter, menu, fragment, oncreateoptionsmenu

I was trying to build a simple fragment in which to show search on the menu, in the debugging doesn't stop at the class.

I have other classes for the main Fragment and other 2 fragments, I want to show the search as 2 options at the header or inside the fragment.

```
public class Frag3 extends Fragment implements Filterable {

    SearchView searchView;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle saveInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag3_layout, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        //MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);

        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu) ;
        menu.findItem(R.id.search_view).setVisible(true);
        //searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
        //final MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search_view);


        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }




    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I have added the placeholder fragment

```
public class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    private PageViewModel pageViewModel;

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int index) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, index);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        pageViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(PageViewModel.class);
        int index = 1;
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            index = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);
        }
        pageViewModel.setIndex(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(
            @NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        final TextView textView = root.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        pageViewModel.getText().observe(this, new Observer<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable String s) {
                textView.setText(s);
            }
        });
        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.search_view).setVisible(true);


        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    }
}
```

Menu Layout in below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search_view"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        android:title="Search View"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be enough information to reproduce your problem? This fragment on its own doesn't seem to do anything!

Comment: @HenryTwist, I have added the main Fragment class, and menu layout

Comment: when I click on Fragment in debug mode, it doesnt enter onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: I have tried your code and it all works fine for me. Have you checked that your activities `onCreateOptionsMenu` is being called?

Comment: does the search icon is showing?

Comment: @HenryTwist for me it doesnt enter to onCreateOptionsMenu class

Comment: I didn't test it with a menu, just whether `onCreateOptionsMenu` was called, which it was.

Comment: Can you include the code where you're setting your action bar?